# why the function in a function can't use the enviroment of its parent function in R while parallel running

Tags: r

Here, I have a function named `f()` for example, and I import some packages I need. Also I defined a function named `g()`in `f()`. But I find`g()`can't use the functions defined in the packages I import before, if I want to parallel the g.

```
f=function()
{
   command 1...
   library(pkg1)... # there is a function named t(),for example
   library(pkg2)...
   g=function(x)
   {
      t()  # function from pkg1
   }
   library(parallel)
   cl <- makeCluster(core,outfile="")
   result=parLapply(cl,x,g) # error, the t is not defined
   stopCluster(cl)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to export the function and the library to the cluster,
for example:

```
cl <<- makeCluster(length(Tasks), type = "PSOCK")
clusterEvalQ(cl,c(library(httr),library(XML),library(magrittr),library(xml2)))
```

*clusterEvalQ(cl,expr)* exports the libraries listed to the cluster so it can use them.
you have to do the same thing with variables only using *clusterExport(cl,varlist)*